# Подскажите как правильно отсортировать список

Tags: python, list, математика, числа

```
y = int(input())
c = list()

for i in range(x):
    v = str(i)[0]
    b = len(str(i))
    if v * b == str(i):
        c.append(i)
```

Код должен принимать 2 значения, первое - количество комнат, второе - комната на которой был ответ ( число 100% будет скучным, то есть 1;2;11;22;22222;99999 )
с созданием и отделением скучных чисел код справляется, но похожие скучные числа должны стоять рядом в том плане, что 1;11;111 должны стоять вместе. мой же вывод из кода при вводных значениях (100;22)

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]

в идеале список должен выглядеть вот так

> [1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33, 4, 44, 5, 55, 6, 66, 7, 77, 8, 88, 9, 99]

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Answer (score 2):

Просто с использованием параметра `key`:

1.

```py
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
c.sort(key=str)
print(c)
```

2. 

```py
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
c = sorted(c, key=str)
print(c)
```

PS: Эти варианты равнозначны.

Вывод:

```py
[1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33, 4, 44, 5, 55, 6, 66, 7, 77, 8, 88, 9, 99]
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: поясню почему оно работает:
Метод `sort()` вызывается непосредственно на самом списке и принимает ту же функцию `key`, как и `sorted()`

Comment: Если мой ответ вас устроил, то *примите* его (серая галка слева).

Comment: @Ruslan да, только я использую метод  `sort`, а не функцию `sorted`.

Comment: @чистов_n поправил

Comment: @чистов_n добавь мой ответ в совой, а я свой удалю, чтоб одним постом был ответ

Comment: @Ruslan добавил.

Comment: @чистов_n ну отформатируй уж код по красоте)

Comment: Лямбда не нужна, указание встроенной функции в качестве ключа сортировки тоже должно работать: `key=str`. Лямбда - это ведь тоже функция, только анонимная. И всё, что она у вас делает - это вызывает другую функцию с тем же параметром.